# Short story involving a company that wipes workers' memories at the end of every workday and a weird, unintentional love triangle

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read it online sometime around 2015-2016; might've been published much earlier. I thought it was the inspiration for the TV show *Severance* (2022), as the stories are nearly identical, but I can't find any mention of it on the internet.

Basically it was about a guy who works for a company that has valuable intellectual property/proprietary info, so their employees sign contracts to agree to be unable to access their work memories after leaving work (through a memory-blocking implant/some office entrance checkpoint or something). Their at-work selves remember everything, but outside they don't remember what happens in the office.

The main character guy falls in love with a girl outside work. But he comes to the office and realizes she's a co-worker his at-work self despises. She's also dating/"married" to his best co-worker friend. He chastises his friend/the girl for having a relationship at work, knowing their outside selves would never know about it. They're pissed and order him to figure something out.

There's a lot of hilarity as the guy desperately tries to communicate to his out-of-work self to stop having a relationship with her, I think he does stuff like talking to HR or hiding notes in crevices of his body, but the "inspectors" at work always find them, so it's all fruitless. I think one of the characters also tries to quit, but their out-of-work selves have no idea, so they just come back to work the next day, haha. His best friend and the girl are just disgusted more and more. Eventually, I think he marries the girl outside of work and all of their at-work selves just accept their helplessness.

It was a really funny, existential, dark story.

Also, maybe helpful--I thought it might be on a site like Daily Science Fiction, as I used to frequent it a lot at the time, but I went through some of the likely categories and couldn't find it. :/ Don't remember if it's really there though.

Comment: See also "Paycheck", by Phillip K. Dick.

Comment: @ToddWilcox "[That] story was later made, with various alterations, into the film Paycheck in 2003 directed by John Woo and starring Ben Affleck."

Comment: @stannius You got it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Character is What You Are](https://dailysciencefiction.com/science-fiction/virtual-reality/michael-r-fletcher/character-is-what-you-are) by Michael R. Fletcher, originally published Friday, December 9th, 2011

Memories suppressed outside of work

> I blamed the memory plug. It was either that or accept responsibility
> for how my life had turned out. **The Plugs, while inserted, scrambled
> all memories created during that time. Those memories could only be
> accessed while that same plug was worn. It was the ultimate in
> security and protecting the hallowed company's all-important
> intellectual property rights.** Unplug at the end of the day and you had
> no idea what you'd been doing for the last ten hours.

Love life complications

> I stood, rooted to the floor, staring at Jason as he exited the
> IntroSpec security cordon. "Fuck me."
>
> "What's up?" Jason asked.
>
> "That woman you're having that lunchroom love affair with--"
>
> "Raaj, the other Senior Systems Architect."
>
> "Yeah. It's her."
>
> "Who is her?"
>
> "The woman. The one I met last night. The one I went on a date with."
>
> We stood staring at each other. Jason recovered first.
>
> "You went on a date with Raaj, my girlfriend?"

Comment: That's it thank you so much! And oh my god, today is only five days away from the date mentioned in the story...if that isn't prophetic I don't know what is.
Very curious to know what was your search process of finding it?

Comment: I used Google with the specification site:dailysciencefiction.com and "memory" and "work" I think