What short story is Severance NOT based on?
{This question contains spoilers for the first half of the first episode of Severance (2022), only.}
I recently watched the first episode of Severance, and immediately recognised the core mechanic: individuals have their memories artificially split into two by their employer: their daily life and their work life, and they can't remember the other half of their life as they live it.
"Oh yes," I thought, "This is a short story I read a couple of years ago. They must have turned it into a whole TV series. Something about a couple having a loving relationship not realising that they hate each other at work, or was it vice versa? Trying to send secret messages between the two versions of the selves, written on notes or on their skin, but the employer always managed to find it or clean them up before they woke up again."
While the core idea was exactly the same (and not too dissimilar in parts to The Tunnel under the World), the plot of the series was very different. There is no "based on" credit and the Internet tells me it is original to show creator Dan Erickson.
Which leaves me in a quandary: What story did I read that allowed me to recognise the basic concept well before it was explained to the viewer?
[I don't want to be seen as accusing Erickson of stealing an idea; the timeline means I may have read the story after Severance was written.]

Is it the story given as an answer here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279891/short-story-involving-a-company-that-wipes-workers-memories-at-the-end-of-every?rq=1

Seems like it to me

@Clara: That's the story. Thank you for your help. I have voted to close as Duplicate; I think that's the best result here. I welcome your vote too.
